# Copying usernames and password from a file onto another in C

Tags: c, file, text

I have to write a c program that copies usernames and password from two different files and matches them on a third file. I don't really know how to tackle this problem. There are 20 elements in both username.txt and password.txt. I know I can use fread and fwrite to read blocks of information at a time from a text file. I tried running the program but it gives me the error cannot open file. How can I fix this issue?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BUFF_SIZE 1000

int main()
{
    FILE *usernames, *passwords, *merged_file;
    char a, c;
    passwords = fopen("/Users/mcicco/Desktop/passwords.txt", "r");
    usernames = fopen("/Users/mcicco/Desktop/usernames.txt ", "r");
    merged_file = fopen("/Users/mcicco/Desktop/merged.txt" , "w");

    if (usernames == NULL || passwords ==NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file \n");
        return (-1);
    }

    c = fgetc(usernames);
    a = fgetc(passwords);
    while (c != EOF && a!= EOF)
    {
        fputc(c, merged_file);
        c = fgetc(usernames);
        fputc(a, merged_file);
        a=fgetc(passwords);
    }

    fclose(usernames);
    fclose(passwords);
    fclose(merged_file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `BUFF_SIZE` is not used here, so you're probably failing to allocate a buffer at all. Reading character by character is going to be quite slow for anything but trivial amounts of data.

Comment: You're probably supposed to read *lines* from the two input files, and write them combined to the output file.

Comment: The simple explanation is that the file names are wrong/mispelled, or the files don't exist.

Comment: Do error checking on each `fopen` call separately, and use `perror` instead of `printf` to print the error message.  That will tell you *why* the call failed (and which one).

Comment: I found the problem, there was an extra space in the fopen function. However, the text files are not being merged.

Comment: You are intercalating the characters from both input filenames. I suppose what you want is intercalate the lines so that, read line by line instead of character by character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the file one character at a time is too slow. Just read one line at a time, and write one line or two lines at a time:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *passwords = fopen("/Users/mcicco/Desktop/passwords.txt", "r");
    FILE *usernames = fopen("/Users/mcicco/Desktop/usernames.txt ", "r");
    FILE *merged_file = fopen("/Users/mcicco/Desktop/merged.txt" , "w");
    if (usernames == NULL || passwords == NULL || merged_file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file \n");
        return (-1);
    }

    char username[1024];
    char password[1024];
    while(1)
    {
        if(!fgets(username, sizeof(username), usernames))
            break;
        if(!fgets(password, sizeof(password), passwords))
            break;
        username[strcspn(username, "\n")] = 0;
        password[strcspn(password, "\n")] = 0;
        fprintf(merged_file, "%s\n%s\n", username, password);
    }
    fclose(usernames);
    fclose(passwords);
    fclose(merged_file);    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. uses `fgets()` to quickly read each line of the two input files
4. uses `strchr()` to find any newline in the input buffer
5. uses a simple assignment to replace any newline with a NUL byte
6. properly checks for errors on the calls to `fopen()`
7. properly cleans up if any call to `fopen()` fails
8. makes use of the `#define BUFF_SIZE`
9. takes into account the comments to the question.
10. documents why each header file is included
11. follows the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*
12. encourages ease of readability and understanding by separating code blocks ( `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line
13. makes the assumption that both of the input files contain the same number of rows
14. makes the assumption that for a line that contains a user name, the same line on the other file contains the password
15. makes the assumption that the desired content of the output file is: `username password`

and now, the proposed code.

```
#include <stdio.h>   // FILE, fopen(), fprintf(), fgets(), perror()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string.h>  // strchr()

#define BUFF_SIZE 1000

int main( void )
{
    FILE *usernames;
    FILE *passwords;
    FILE *merged_file;

    if( NULL == (passwords = fopen("/Users/mcicco/Desktop/passwords.txt", "r") ) )
    {
        perror( "fopen to read passwords.txt failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    if( NULL == (usernames = fopen("/Users/mcicco/Desktop/usernames.txt", "r") ) )
    {
        perror( "fopen to read usernames.txt failed" );
        fclose( passwords );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    if( NULL == (merged_file = fopen("/Users/mcicco/Desktop/merged.txt" , "w") ) )
    {
        perror( "fopen to write merged.txt failed" );
        fclose( passwords );
        fclose( usernames );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    char passwordsBuffer[ BUFF_SIZE ];
    char usernamesBuffer[ BUFF_SIZE ];

    while( fgets( passwordsBuffer, sizeof passwordsBuffer, passwords ) &&
           fgets( usernamesBuffer, sizeof usernamesBuffer, usernames ) )
    {
        char *newline;
        if( NULL != (newline = strchr( passwordsBuffer, '\n' ) ) )
        {
            *newline = '\0';
        }

        if( NULL != (newline = strchr( usernamesBuffer, '\n' ) ) )
        {
            *newline = '\0';
        }

        fprintf( merged_file, "%s %s\n", usernamesBuffer, passwordsBuffer );
    }

    fclose(usernames);
    fclose(passwords);
    fclose(merged_file);
    return 0;
}
```